# Sum bounded in probability

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^N|c_n| = O(1)$ and that $X_n = O_p(1)$ in the sense that for every $\epsilon>0,\exists M<\infty$ such that $$\sup_nP(|X_n|>M)<\epsilon$$

Can we claim that $\sum_{n=1}^Nc_nX_n = O_p(1)?$ Clearly, if we knew that $\sup_n|X_n| = O_p(1)$, then the answer would be trivial as $$P\left(\left|\sum_nc_nX_n\right|>M\right) \leq P\left(\sum_n|c_n|\sup_n|X_n| > M\right).$$

Can we say something about more general case?

Comment: Since the sum of the $c_n$ is $O(1)$, doesn't that mean we can find a constant $C$ such that $\lvert c_n \rvert < C$? Then $P\left(\lvert\sum_n c_n X_n\rvert > M\right) \le P\left(\sum_n (C+1) \lvert X_n\rvert > M\right)$. Since $X_n$ is $O_p(1)$, there exists $M/(C+1) < \infty$ such that this probability is bounded by epsilon, which I think implies your general case.

Comment: $P(|\sum_{n=1}^Nc_nX_n|>M) \leq P(\sum_{n=1}^N|X_n|>M/C) \leq \sum_{n=1}^NP(|X_n|>M/CN)$

Comment: How do you get the last inequality?

Comment: I think it's correct if you replace the outer $\sum_{n=1}^N$ with a $\sup_n$

Comment: I used $P(|X_1| + |X_2| \geq c) = P(|X_1| + |X_2| \geq c/2 + c/2) \leq P(|X_1|>c/2) + P(|X_2|>c/2)$. I'm still having difficulties to show what I need because of the sum. How do you obtain the inequality with a $sup_n$?

Comment: $\sum_n \lvert X_n\rvert \le N \sup_n \lvert X_n\rvert$, then plug in to your second equality and move constants around. I should have specified in the earlier comment that the sup goes inside the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I'm still having difficulties to see the result: $P(\sum_{n=1}^N|X_n| > M/C) \leq P(N\sup_n|X_n| > M/C)$. This depends on $N$ and we don't know whether $sup_n|X_n| = O_P(1)$.

Comment: Are you suggesting to bound $P\left(\sum_n|c_n|\sup_n|X_n| > M\right) \leq P(\sup_n|X_n|>MC) \leq N\sup_nP(|X_n|>MC)?$ If $\epsilon$ depends on $N$, then it seems that $M$ depends on N. I'm missing something...